# GridLayout too big in Android

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

My `GridLayout` looks like that:

[image]

But it should look like that:

[image]

I don't know how to fix that error. I don't use `dp` because I want to support multiple screen sizes.

My `.xml` file:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:columnCount="12"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="6" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="9" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="12" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="15" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button18"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="18" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button21"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="21" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button24"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="24" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button27"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="27" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button30"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="30" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button33"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="33" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button36"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="36" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="5" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="8" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="11" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="14" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button17"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="17" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button20"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="20" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button23"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="23" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button26"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="26" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button29"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="29" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button32"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="32" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button35"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="35" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="10" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="13" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="16" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button19"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="19" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button22"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="22" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button25"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="25" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button28"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="28" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button31"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="31" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button34"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="34" />
</GridLayout>
```

Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that dp unity is relative to pixel ratio of the screen and are automatically adapted by android to the current display.

Keep in mind that you can specify different values for a dimension variable, based on screen size, screen density and screen orientation.

What you are trying to do is to set a dimension relative to the wheel, that is not an element, so to what do you want to set buttons grid width? You can't achieve your goal in this way.

For me you should split your background into 2 images: the first with the wheels and the second with the rest of the background. Then you could use a RelativeLayout in which the wheel is anchored to the left of his parent and the second image is the background of your GridLayout, anchored to the right of the wheel image. In this manner you can set your GridLayout width as `match_parent` that in conjunction with `toRightOf` results in a GridLayout that occupy all the empty space on the right.

I give you an example:

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width=“match_parent”
    android:layout_height="match_parent”>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wheel” 
        android:layout_width=“wrap_content”
            android:layout_height="match_parent”
        android:src=“@drawable/wheel” />

<GridLayout 
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:layout_width=“match_parent”
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:toRightOf=“@+id/wheel”
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:columnCount="12"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="6" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="9" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="12" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="15" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button18"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="18" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button21"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="21" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button24"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="24" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button27"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="27" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button30"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="30" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button33"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="33" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button36"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="36" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="5" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="8" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="11" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="14" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button17"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="17" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button20"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="20" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button23"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="23" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button26"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="26" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button29"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="29" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button32"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="32" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button35"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="35" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="10" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="13" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="16" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button19"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="19" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button22"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="22" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button25"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="25" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button28"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="28" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button31"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="31" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button34"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="34" />
</GridLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I can't try it, let me know if it works

Comment: i think use android:layout_width=“wrap_content” instead of     android:layout_width=“match_parent” in GridLayout. @firegloves

Comment: no because the conjunction of match_parent and toRightOf and alignParentRight should results into the use of all the available space onto the right of the wheel

Comment: ohhh..yaaa you used  toRightOf. I forget it.

Comment: So could I use dp and it looks the same on bigger devices?

Comment: no, it's a bit more complex. but you can use different dimens.xml file to match different screen sizes. you should use values-[identificator] folder names to achieve this goal

Comment: @mafioso your problem is you can't know how many dp your GridLayout need to be to don't overlap wheel image.